# how add_submenu_page set for multiple role?

Tags: wordpress

I have created some wordpress admin menu and I want to add these menu for multiple roles:

```
add_submenu_page('Events', 'Colloqui', 'subscriber, editor', 'events', 'ww_events');
```

This is only working for subscriber role. But, I want this menu also for administrator role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved like this.Get the current user role and then add specific admin menu to specific role.

```
    $c_id = get_current_user_id();
    $user = new WP_User($c_id);
    $u_role =  $user->roles[0];
    if(($u_role == "administrator")) {
    function register_merchant() {
    add_submenu_page( $parent_slug, $page_title, $menu_title, 'administrator' , 
    $menu_slug, $function );
    }
    }
    else if($u_role == "custom_role") {
    function register_merchant() {
    add_submenu_page( $parent_slug, $page_title, $menu_title, 'custom_role' , 
    $menu_slug, $function );
    }}
    else {
        function register_merchant() {
    add_submenu_page( $parent_slug, $page_title, $menu_title, 'custom_role' , 
    $menu_slug, $function );
} }
```

Comment: Use user roles instead of capabilities is deprecated now. You should create a custom capability and then add that capability users like how @ojrask suggested in another answer.

Comment: @Sudar nice. very simple

Answer (score 7):

I would create a custom capability for the `subscriber` and `editor` roles.

```
$subs = get_role('subscriber');
$editor = get_role('editor');

$subs->add_cap('custom_menu_access');
$editor->add_cap('custom_menu_access');
```

Then create the new menu item with said capability (see the fourth parameter in the following function call).

```
add_submenu_page('some-parent-slug', 'Events', 'Colloqui', 'custom_menu_access', 'events', 'ww_events');
```

Remember to add capabilities and roles only on plugin/theme activation, as they are saved to the database.

Answer (score 0):

For permission of menu, you have to assign capability for the page. Fourth parameter of `add_submenu_page` is `$capability`.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page

```
add_submenu_page( $parent_slug, $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function );
```

Check this codex page for available capabilities in WordPress. https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities

Comment: This is my custom menu with some extra functionality so I can not add capability here . Just I want this menu for multiple roles